# TextView loses text changes when listview is scrolled down

Tags: android-listview, textview, android

I'm trying to implement the Show More and Show less functionality on my text view, which should expand and collapse on clicking Show More or Show Less text vice versa.

Problem is if i expand the text view on clicking Show More & scroll down the list ,it again collapses.

Thanks.

```
private void bindPostContent(ViewHolder holder, Cursor c) {
    //Main text in HTML format
    String postContent = c.getString(thoughtC);
    holder.tvPostHtml.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.tvPostHtml.setText(Html.fromHtml(c.getString(thoughtC)));
    Linkify.addLinks(holder.tvPostHtml, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(postContent)) {
        if (postContent.length() > 240) {
            resizePostContent(holder.tvPostHtml, "...Show More", true);
        }
    } else {
        holder.tvPostHtml.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    //Display attachments
    AttachmentContainer container = new AttachmentContainer(tid, holder.llAttachmentContainer,
            ThoughtContainerType.THOUGHT,
            context, c.getString(attachmentC),
            attachJsonMapper, pollState);
    value = container.value;
    container.renderAttachmentViews();
}

public void resizePostContent(final TextView tvPostContent, final String showMoreLessLabel, final boolean showMore) {

    if (tvPostContent.getTag() == null) {
        tvPostContent.setTag(tvPostContent.getText());
    }
    ViewTreeObserver vto = tvPostContent.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            ViewTreeObserver obs = tvPostContent.getViewTreeObserver();
            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            if (showMore) {
                String text = tvPostContent.getText().subSequence(0, 240) + " " + showMoreLessLabel;
                tvPostContent.setText(text);
                tvPostContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                tvPostContent.setText(showMoreLess(Html.fromHtml(tvPostContent.getText().toString()), tvPostContent, showMoreLessLabel, showMore));
            } else {
                String text = tvPostContent.getText().subSequence(0, tvPostContent.getText().length()) + " " + showMoreLessLabel;
                tvPostContent.setText(text);
                tvPostContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                tvPostContent.setText(showMoreLess(Html.fromHtml(tvPostContent.getText().toString()), tvPostContent, showMoreLessLabel, showMore));
            } tvPostContent.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
        }
    });

}

private  SpannableStringBuilder showMoreLess(final Spanned postContentSpanned, final TextView tvPostContent, final String showMoreLessLabel, final boolean viewMore) {
    String str = postContentSpanned.toString();
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(postContentSpanned);
    if (str.contains(showMoreLessLabel)) {
        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                tvPostContent.setOnClickListener(null);
                if (viewMore) {
                    tvPostContent.setLayoutParams(tvPostContent.getLayoutParams());
                    tvPostContent.setText(tvPostContent.getTag().toString());
                    resizePostContent(tvPostContent, "Show Less", false);
                } else {
                    tvPostContent.setLayoutParams(tvPostContent.getLayoutParams());
                    tvPostContent.setText(tvPostContent.getTag().toString());
                    resizePostContent(tvPostContent, "...Show More", true);
                }

            }
            @Override public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds){
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                ds.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.newsfeed_item_action_performed));
            }
        }, str.indexOf(showMoreLessLabel), str.indexOf(showMoreLessLabel) + showMoreLessLabel.length(), 0);

    }
    return ssb;
}
```